# Converting object to an arbitrary object with Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

I am trying to save an arbitrary object to a MongoDB repository. The class could be anything:

```
data class MyClass(val someValue: String)
```

If I create a converter that converts the class `MyClass` to a String, it is picked up by Spring and converts seamlessly:

```
@Bean
fun myClassToString(): Converter<MyClass, String> = Converter {
    it.someValue
}

// ...

val object = MyClass("whatever")
repository.save(object) // Will be saved as a String, "whatever"
```

However, if I try to convert this to a DBObject (or any other POJO), although Spring sees the Converter Bean, it doesn't call it:

```
@Bean
fun myClassToObject(): Converter<MyClass, DBObject> = Converter {
    BasicDBObject(mapOf("theValue" to it.value))
}

// ...

val object = MyClass("whatever")
repository.save(object)

// Will be saved as:
{
  "someValue": "whatever"
}
// not under the field "theValue".
```

The same happens if I try to convert this to some other arbitrary object:

```
fun myClassToOther(): Converter<MyClass, OtherClass>
```

or directly to a map:

```
fun myClassToMap(): Converter<MyClass, Map<String, Any>>
```

The converters are all created and registered in a `MongoCustomConversions` Bean:

```
@Bean
fun customMongoConversions(customConverters: List<Converter<out Any, out Any>>): MongoCustomConversions {
    return MongoCustomConversions(customConverters)
}
```

I know that they are registered and converting to a `String` demonstrates that they work. As far as I can tell, this follows the example shown [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/com/baeldung/converter/UserWriterConverter.java). The only difference is that the objects I'm trying to convert aren't directly `@Document`s, but sub-objects. In other words, it's more like:

```
val object = Document(MyClass("whatever"))
repository.save(object)
```

I can't see how that should change anything (*edit: it doesn't; `Converter<Document, DBObject>` doesn't work either*).

A `StdSerializer` with `@JsonSerialize` doesn't work either. I realise that these trivial examples can be completed other ways, but I am looking for the flexibility of a converter. More concretely, I am trying to serialise an object with a `Class<T>` in it.

Am I missing some annotation or some Spring config somewhere?